# TensorFlow r0.11 gives TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'argv'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run a tensorflow example.

Here is my setup:

Ubuntu 16.04

cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb

cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.0-ga.tgz

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

I tried running this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
a = tf.constant(10)
b = tf.constant(32)
print(sess.run(a + b))
```

I saw this:

```
dan@e80:~/tf11 $ 
dan@e80:~/tf11 $ python tf10.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce 940MX
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.2415
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.95GiB
Free memory: 3.50GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
42
dan@e80:~/tf11 $ 
dan@e80:~/tf11 $ 
dan@e80:~/tf11 $
```

I tried running this:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py

I saw this:

```
dan@e80:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist $ 
dan@e80:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist $ 
dan@e80:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist $ python mnist_with_summaries.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_with_summaries.py", line 205, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'argv'
dan@e80:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist $ 
dan@e80:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist $ 
dan@e80:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist $
```

I'd welcome any ideas on how to debug this.

Comment: Can you just remove `, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed` part? `main` is not using them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `argv` was added to the `app.run()` function recently. So to make it work, you have to either remove the `argv=...` argument or build TensorFlow from source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Was using the master branch, and get a release of the tensorflow repository solved it.

> git clone -b r0.11 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git

If you are using conda, be sure to install/upgrade to a newer version as bellow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html

> 1) Create a conda environment called tensorflow:

```
"Python 2.7 "

$ conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7

"Python 3.4"

$ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.4

"Python 3.5"

$ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

> 2) Activate tensorfow:

```
source activate tensorflow
```

> 3) Installation

```
 conda install -c jjhelmus tensorflow=0.10.0rc0
```

Me I choose a particular release available as conda package.